# c++ server htons to java ntohs client conversion

Tags: java, c++, data-conversion, htonl

I am creating a small TFTP client
 server app where server is developed
 using c++ and client using java.

Here i am sending "block count" value
 using  `htons` conversion.

But i am not able to convert it back
 to its original value at client.

For example if am sending block count
 `ntohs(01)` (2 bytes) from server to
 client. Client is reading in bytes.
 Value which I am receiving is byte 0
 and byte 1.

Please if any one can provide a
 solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you meant that you use `ntohs` to *decode* the values read from the network, and `htons` to *encode* the values sent over the network.

Look into [`ByteBuffer#getShort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort%28%29) in concert with [`ByteBuffer#order(ByteOrder)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29). *Network byte order* is *big endian*, so use the value [`ByteOrder#BIG_ENDIAN`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#BIG_ENDIAN) to configure your `ByteBuffer` properly. Note that `BIG_ENDIAN` is the default order, but in this case it would be good form to state your preference explicitly.

---

You didn't mention what you're using for network communications in Java. If it's a `java.net.Socket`, you can call `Socket#getChannel()` to get a `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel`, a subtype of `java.nio.channels.ByteChannel`, with which you can use `ByteBuffer` to read and write data.

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void somemethod(){

    byte[] fileDataFull = new byte[516];
    byte[] receivedCounter = new byte[2];

    readLength = in.read(fileDataFull);

    receivedCounter[0] = fileDataFull[2];
    receivedCounter[1] = fileDataFull[3];

   if (expectedPktCount == convertntohs(receivedCounter)){

   }

   byte[] b = converthtons((short) expectedPktCount);

}

    private short convertntohs(byte[] value) {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
        return buf.getShort();
    }

    private byte[] converthtons(short sValue) {
        byte[] baValue = new byte[2];
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(baValue);
        return buf.putShort(sValue).array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's numbers internally are always in network byte order, even on systems where the native integers/doubles are not. This means that you can convert any number coming in to Java with any of the base input streams that do this kind of conversion - that implement java.io.DataInput. ByteBuffer also works if you are using a java.nio.Channel but there you can change the endianness (`ByteBuffer.order()`), though the default is correct for network byte ordering and Java internal storage.

By the way, I think you mean to use `htons` but in the example you show `ntohs`. Sending from C++ you want to convert *h*ost order to *n*etwork order. Receiving from Java (or any client) your server would convert back using `ntohs`.