# send a int from objective-c to java by socket,but the value changed in java side

Tags: java, objective-c, int

I send a int in a NSData like this:

```
 NSData* dataLength = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&theInt length:sizeof(theInt)];
```

then in java side, I get a int like this:

```
int theInt = aInputStreamOfSocket.readInt();
```

but the value changed! In my case, I send 1225516 and get 749933056
what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trouble is a difference in [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Intel based processors use little-endian byte order while network based transports are almost always big-endian. Java thus expects big-endian for `readInt()`. Ideally you find a way to send the int as big-endian to conform to expected behavior. I however don't have that code offhand, so here's how to read little-endian on the Java side:

```
int ch1 = aInputStreamOfSocket.read();
int ch2 = aInputStreamOfSocket.read();
int ch3 = aInputStreamOfSocket.read();
int ch4 = aInputStreamOfSocket.read();
if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0) {
    throw new EOFException();
}
int theInt = ch1 + (ch2 << 8) + (ch3 << 16) + (ch4 << 24);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the hex for both of those numbers

```
1225516   = 0x0012B32C  
749933056 = 0x2CB31200
```

You can see that the byte order (a.k.a. endianness) is reversed.

Generally, if you're sending data over a socket, you convert from the local byte order to network byte order with the functions `htonl`, `htons`, etc. On the receiving end, you convert from network byte order back to the local byte order. In java, you can do this by setting the byte order on the buffer with [ByteBuffer#order(ByteOrder)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800983/c-server-htons-to-java-ntohs-client-conversion) also.