# Efficiently read binary data into int[]

Tags: java, android

I have binary data in a file (a list of 32-bit integer values) that I need to get into an int array efficiently. I can't see any way to do this other than loading the data into a byte[] and then converting it into an int[] one element at a time. This is too slow for the amount of data I need to load. It takes about 3 seconds to do the conversion on an actual phone. Reading the data from the file in the byte[] is pretty much instantaneous.

Are there any libraries that use native methods for reading an int[] from a file, or for converting a byte[] to int[]?

Comment: Are you sure it is the conversion that takes most of the time? I'm not convinced. I'd look at I/O first.

Comment: Yes, I have logging around the operations and the iteration through the array is where all the time is. In fact I have solved the problem by writing a native method to do the manipulation. In C++ it is a simple cast to convert the data.

Comment: Hey Chris! Do you think you might paste the code here, or maybe on pastebin.com, and post a link to it here? I believe this small piece of code might be a nice enhancement for Android developers. Did you also try the NIO package as I wrote, and if so: Do you have some performance comparisons? I would be very interested in them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the classes of the [NIO package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)? The class [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) has a method [asIntBuffer()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer%28%29), where you can get an IntBuffer view of the ByteBuffer. Then you should be able to get the content as integers by calling [get(int[] dst)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#get%28int%5B%5D%29).

The initial ByteBuffer is available by using [file channels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).

Comment: Amount of operations involved in creating IntBuffer is quite large. I wonder if manual a<<24+b<<16+c<<8+d would be much faster.

Comment: I was trying to use the NIO package, but was running into trouble using the array() method which doesn't exist for a buffer created from a byte[]. But it looks like get() is the answer.

Comment: @road to yamburg: This might be. But chances are high that the actual implementation of byte buffers are in native code, and therefore are much faster. In fact, I believe the NIO package of Android is done natively - I could not find a working byte buffer implementation in Java there. @Chris: Exactly - you can not use the array() method because your IntBuffer is not backed by an int[] array, but a byte[] array. The documentation of array() on http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#array%28%29 makes this pretty clear. :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this yet:

```
File file = new File("binary.file");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bin);

int count = (int) (file.length() / 4);
int[] values = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    values[i] = din.readInt();
}
```

Even on a phone this should be relatively fast, unless you're just dealing with a huge file.

Comment: Good point, it only works for big-endian ints. Typically it's used for transport, however the OP can reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712066/send-a-int-from-objective-c-to-java-by-socket-but-the-value-changed-in-java-side/5712128#5712128 for reading little-endian if necessary.

Comment: @road to yamburg - it is not unreasonable to assume that the OP is trying to read a binary file created on the phone itself or by some application on another Java / Android platform ... and that the file will be big-endian.

Comment: The problem is that my array is 1.5MB in size, and any iteration over the elements in Java like this is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a fairly careful experiment using serialize/deserialize, DataInputStream vs ObjectInputStream, both based on ByteArrayInputStream to avoid IO effects. For a million ints, readObject was about 20msec, readInt was about 116.  The serialization overhead on a million-int array was 27 bytes.

Having said that, object serialization is sort of evil, and you have to have written the data out with a Java program.